# POST xml Bad Request 400

Tags: java, post, curl, xmlhttprequest, httpurlconnection

имеется XML файл match.xml, через curl легко отправить POST и добавить в базу.

```
curl -F "xml=@match.xml" web_url
```

Стандартная реализация POST на Java возвращает мне POST Response Code :: 400 Bad Request

```
public static void sendPOST(String data) throws IOException {
    URL obj = new URL(FinalConstants.BETRADAR_UPLOAD);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

    // For POST only - START
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
    os.write(data.getBytes());
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    // For POST only - END

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("POST Response Code :: " + responseCode);

    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { //success
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        // print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());
    } else {
        System.out.println("POST request not worked");
    }
}
```

и при таких настройках возвращает такую же ошибку

```
        httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
        httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");


        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
```

Подскажите как работает `curl -F`? Как мне корректно отправить данные ?

**UPD**

Несколько вариантов попробовал с HttpClient и все они выдают следующее

> HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [Server: nginx, Date: Thu,
>   09 Feb 2017 20:07:18 GMT, Content-Type: application/octet-stream,
>   Content-Length: 0, Connection: keep-alive]}

1 Вариант

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(FinalConstants.UPLOAD);
    HttpEntity entity =
            new ByteArrayEntity(data.getBytes("UTF-8"),
                    ContentType.TEXT_XML); 
    post.setEntity(entity);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

2 вариант

```
InputStream in ;
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(data, ContentType.create(
    "text/xml", Consts.UTF_8));
entity.setChunked(true);
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost( FinalConstants.UPLOAD);

httppost.setEntity(entity);

HttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);
System.out.println(response.toString());
in=response.getEntity().getContent();
String body = IOUtils.toString(in);
System.out.println(body);
```

Также вариант с использованием файла

```
builder.addBinaryBody(
    "file",
    new FileInputStream(f),
    ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, // Также как и с другими типами 
    f.getName()
);
```

Все таки мне хотелось бы отправить строку, а не файл

**UPD2**

```
public static void sendPOST(File file) throws IOException {
    try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
        final HttpPost uploadFile = new HttpPost(FinalConstants.UPLOAD);
        final HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder
                .create()
                .addBinaryBody("xml", file).build();
        uploadFile.setEntity(entity);
        final HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(uploadFile);
        System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
    }
}


java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.create(Ljava/lang/String;[Lorg/apache/http/NameValuePair;)Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;

    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder.buildEntity(MultipartEntityBuilder.java:219)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder.build(MultipartEntityBuilder.java:240)
```

Comment: а использовать какую-нибудь библиотеку для это вы не хотите?

Comment: Например какую   ?

Comment: например, [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/)

Comment: @MikhailVaysman не помогло. я что-то не так делаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`curl -F` эмулирует отправку HTTP формы, `"xml=@match.xml"` - прикрепить файл с указанным именем.
Для такого HTTP запроса (с прикрепленным файлом), Content-Type должен быть `multipart/form-data`, а одна из частей такого запроса (part) должна иметь имя `xml` (для Вашего примера) и содержать файл с соответсвующим Content-Type.
Честно говоря, как уже подсказали в комменте к вопросу, проще использовать библиотеку HttpClient от Apache.
Примеров как отправлять `multipart/form-data` с использованием HttpClient полно, вот первый попавшийся из гугла: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378920/how-can-i-make-a-multipart-form-data-post-request-using-java

**Правка:** Вот такой код дает такой-же запрос как и `curl -F "xml=@match.xml" web_url`

```
    try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
        final HttpPost uploadFile = new HttpPost("web_url");
        final HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create().addBinaryBody("xml", new File("match.xml")).build();
        uploadFile.setEntity(entity);
        final HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(uploadFile);
        System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
    }
```

Также надо добавить следующие зависимости (Maven):

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: не помогло. я что-то не так делаю

Comment: а на стороне сервера есть возможность посмотреть логи?
как вариант - поставить fiddler и посмотреть какой запрос реально уходит при использовании curl, от этого и плясать. Выложите код, если будет завтра время - посмотрю что может быть не так

Comment: код обновил в вопросе. к логам нет доступа

Comment: вы отправляете неправильный запрос, нужен multipart/form-data - посмотрите еще раз на пример в http://stackoverflow.com/a/1379002/2269692  
Вам нужно использовать `MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();`  
и потом  
`builder.addBinaryBody`

Comment: Вот такой примерно запрос посылает curl когда используется флаг `-F` и `"xml=@README"`: https://jpst.it/TaLb

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, добавил код в ответ

Comment: спасибо большое за код. я получит такую же ошибку, как со старыми методами. приложил все к вопросу

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53380/discussion-between-sergi-and-senior-automator).